# Did I forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: java, gwt

i have a project that contains 2 modules client and server

```
Project

-- client
----src/main/java
------com.myProject.gwt.code
----app.gwt.xml
---pom.xml

--server
----src/main/java
------com.myProject.nonGwtCode
--------style.java
----src/main/resources
------server.gwt.xml 
---pom.xml

pom.xml
```

Also `style.java` is used by client and server modules
what i did is

1. i added `<inherits name='server' />` in `app.gwt.xml`
2. i wrote `<source path="com/myProject/nonGwtCode"/>`in `server.gwt.xml`
3. i added the server project to the project classpath from run-> run config
   but i still have that error `No source code is available for type com.myProject.nonGwtCode.style; did you forget to inherit a required module?`

Also when i add the `style.java` to client module it compiles well but i want i to be seen from server module as it is used in both modules .. any help ??
i am investing 2 days for now searching for this error but found nothing.. any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you also make sure to include source code when building the server module? I mean source code and not just class files.

Comment: You should NOT modify the classpath manually or it makes it a nightmare every time you import the maven project. The client should NOT depend on the server if you want to share code between both modules create a third module called "shared". This is the best approach to use multi-module layout. Much more info about this project layout here:
https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes
https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/index.html